# winsock fails to connect to localhost

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock

For my project I am unable to debug the program so i cannot be sure as to why this error occurs.

My server, which is hosted on c# is failing to connect to server on localhost.

Instead of it sending back a "connection" signal to my server, it never connects, I think the code is written well and I can't see any errors, maybe i made a careless mistake somewhere

Also, I HAVE to use gethostbyname instead of getaddrinfo

winsock namespace:

```
SOCKET WinSock::ConnectToServer(PCHAR IP, USHORT Port)
{
    WSADATA WSA;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WSA))
    {
        SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (s != SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            hostent *Host = gethostbyname(IP);
            if (Host != ERROR)
            {
                SOCKADDR_IN Addr;

                Addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
                Addr.sin_port = htons(Port);
                Addr.sin_addr.s_addr = NULL;

                if (bind(s, PSOCKADDR(&Addr), sizeof(Addr)) > 0)
                {
                    return s;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}

BOOL WinSock::SendData(SOCKET s, PBYTE Packet)
{
    DWORD PacketSize = lstrlenA(PCHAR(Packet));
    if (send(s, PCHAR(&PacketSize), 8, 0) > NULL)
    {
        if (send(s, PCHAR(Packet), PacketSize, 0) > NULL)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

main method:

```
int main()
{
    char key = 1;
    SOCKET S = WinSock::ConnectToServer(0, 55480);
    while(true)
    {
        WinSock:SendData(S, (PBYTE)key);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't see any errors because there is absolutely no code checking for errors and reporting it. But `send` returns `ssize_t` so you should not compare that to `NULL`. And `bind` returns either `0` or a negative number, never a positive integer. So comparing `> 0` is useless.

Comment: @Cheatah i unlinked the crt therefore i cant even check for errors, i have to know them.

Comment: @Cheatah so what should i compare bind to instead? == 0/ERROR_SUCCESS?

Comment: the posted code uses several C++ code constructs (which cannot be compiled in C).  Please remove the `c` tag

Comment: the function: `send()` returns a `ssize_t`, Never a pointer, like NULL`

Comment: regarding; * failing to connect to server on localhost* `SOCKET S = WinSock::ConnectToServer(0, 55480);`   the local host IP address is: "127.0.0.1"  not 0 nor NULL.  The function returns <0 if it fails

Comment: regarding: `hostent *Host = gethostbyname(IP);`  1) the returned pointer is for `struct hostent` not `hostent`.  2) the 'IP' being passed is (effectively) NULL rather that a pointer to `127.0.0.1`    3) the function: `gethostbyname()` is obsolete.  Suggest: `getaddrinfo()`.  4) suggest you learn about: `getlasterror()`

Comment: regarding a call to `bind()`  from the MAN page: *On  success,  zero is returned.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is
       set appropriately.*

Comment: NOTE:  the windsock functions are already written.  You do not replace the functions, rather you just need to make the appropriate calls into that library with the appropriate parameters

Comment: one important consideration:  does your firewall allow communication on port: 55480?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not actually making a connection to the server.  You are calling `bind()` to bind the client socket to a *local* port 55480, but that does not create a connection.  You need to instead call `connect()` to connect the client socket to the *remote* port 55480.

Also, your `SendData()` is coded wrong.  It is telling `send()` to send 8 bytes for the `PacketSize`, but a `DWORD` is only 4 bytes in size.  And `send()` does not return `NULL` on failure.  And `send()` is not guaranteed to send all of the requested bytes, so you need to call it in a loop.  And it is customary to send multi-byte integers in network byte order (big endian).

Also, you have coded `SendData()` to expect a null-terminated C-style string, but that is not what your `main()` is actually passing in to it.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
bool WinSock::Init()
{
    WSADATA WSA;
    return (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WSA) == 0);
}

bool WinSock::Cleanup()
{
    return (WSACleanup() == 0);
}

SOCKET WinSock::ConnectToServer(const char *IP, unsigned short Port)
{
    hostent *Host = gethostbyname(IP);
    if ((Host != NULL) && (Host->h_addrtype == AF_INET)
    {
        SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (s != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            SOCKADDR_IN Addr = {};

            Addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            Addr.sin_port = htons(Port);
            Addr.sin_addr.s_addr = * (u_long*) Host->h_addr;

            if (connect(s, PSOCKADDR(&Addr), sizeof(Addr)) != SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                return s;
            }

            closesocket(s);
        }
    }

    return INVALID_SOCKET;
}

bool WinSock::Close(SOCKET s)
{
    return (closesocket(s) == 0);
}

bool WinSock::SendData(SOCKET s, const void* Data, DWORD DataSize)
{
    const char *ptr = (const char*) Data;

    while (DataSize > 0)
    {
        int numSent = send(s, ptr, DataSize, 0);
        if (numSent == SOCKET_ERROR) return false;
        ptr += numSent;
        DataSize -= numSent;
    }

    return true;
}

bool WinSock::SendData(SOCKET s, const char *Packet)
{
    DWORD PacketSize = lstrlenA(Packet);
    DWORD tmp = htonl(PacketSize);
    if (!SendData(s, &tmp, sizeof(tmp)) return false;
    return SendData(s, Packet, PacketSize);
}
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    if (WinSock::Init())
    {
        const char *key = "1";
        SOCKET S = WinSock::ConnectToServer(NULL, 55480);
        if (s != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                WinSock:SendData(S, key);
            }
            WinSock::Close(s);
        }
        WinSock::Cleanup();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
            if (bind(s, PSOCKADDR(&Addr), sizeof(Addr)) > 0)
```

The description of this code is that it is supposed to connect to a server. But the problem is that `bind()` does not connect to any server. It only links the socket to a local port. This is what servers that listen on sockets do. This is, presumably, the same port that the server already opened, hence the `bind()` fails. If the server wasn't listening `bind()` will, ironically, succeed. But it won't be connect to anything, anyway.

You want to use `connect()` and not `bind()`.

Additionally, I have to note that if this function creates a socket first, but then fails to establish a connection for this or any other reason it will return an error indication but fail to close the socket, thus leaking a socket descriptor. You must fix this bug, too.